# Example of green's theorem

Tags: vector-analysis

I have the following field :

$$ \vec{F}=\frac{\left \langle x,y \right \rangle}{x^2+y^2} $$

[image]

The Divergence of this field is zero:

$$ \nabla\cdot \vec{F}=0 $$

If taking circular region, it is clear that there is a flux over the boundary:

$$ \oint \vec{F}\cdot \hat{n} ds\neq0 $$

If applying Green's theorem then the flux will be zero over the boundary of the circle

$$ \oint \vec{F}\cdot \hat{n} ds=\iint_{A}^{} \nabla\cdot \vec{F}dA=0 $$

Am I missing something here?

Comment: If the circular region contains origin, you cannot directly apply Green's theorem or divergence theorem as the vector field is not defined at the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are missed that $\vec F$ is not defined at $(0,0)$.

So you cannot apply Green's Theorem, because $(0,0)\in A$.

If some bounded area $D$ does not have an element $(0,0)$, then you can apply Green's Theorem.

In this case, you have to calculate it directly. Fortunately, if we let $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, then $\hat n=\frac{(x,y)}{r}$.

So $\vec F\cdot\hat n=\frac1r$ holds. If the radius of $A$ is $R$, then $\vec F\cdot\hat n$ has constant value $\frac1R$.

And the length of the circumference of $A$ is $2\pi R$, so $\oint_{\partial A}\vec F\cdot\hat n ds=\oint_{\partial A}\frac1R ds=\frac1R\times2\pi R=2\pi$.